# How to make python scripts executable using cx freeze on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, python

I want to convert my python project into a binary executable using CX Freeze on Ubuntu 14.04. How to do I run CX Freeze on Ubuntu???

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt install cx-freeze
cxfreeze myscript.py
```

There are a load of options for customising this but for a simple script, that should do it. If it's not working, [check out the documentation](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or read `man cxfreeze`.

Anyway, when it works it generates a directory called `dist` that contains an executable (based on the name of the script) and everything it needs to run. To execute from the current directory, just run:

```
./dist/myscript
```

Comment: thanks it's working!!! tell me one more thing that how can i create windows .exe file using cx freeze on ubuntu 14.04???

Comment: You can't [cross-platform freeze](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#freezing-for-other-platforms). You have to run cx-freeze from within Windows to generate a Windows executable.